# C# Breakpoint does not hit when there is CR:CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

My web app needs to generate reports from database.
I used Crystal Reports, but including it my page disables the debug (in which I cannot hit the breakpoint)

While redirecting to a new page(that holds my crystalreport) works as a workaround.

I still want to know why this happens, and make it work.

Things I've tried:

- Reinstall crystal report
- Enabled Optimize Code from Build Project Properties

This is the CrystalReportViewer from my aspx.page

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true"/>
```

Running in:

- Visual Studio 2015
- IIS 10 (Full Installion)
- Windows 10

Additional Info:

- There are no errors, clicking a button with a breakpoint on the onclick event does not hit the breakpoint.
- If I delete the CrystalReportViewer, debugger hits the breakpoint

Comment: I understand it's difficult to share a reproducible code snippet here, but some more information would be useful. Are you setting your breakpoint in your code-behind? Is the breakpoint greyed out with a 'no symbols loaded for this assembly' message? Are you running this in IIS Express or a full IIS installation?

Comment: Hi squiggle, thank you, I was thinking on what info i need to post. 
It's just my first time posting a question here.
I will update the question, anyway, there are no errors, it just don't do anything, even if I literally clicked the a button.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you edit your question to expand on the things you've tried, and respond to my points directly? Your question should be as complete as possible, in order to help other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach to the CR process too.

Comment: what do you mean by attach to the CR process?

Comment: Debug, attach to process, search for the relevant processes and attach.